# How can I get the sheet name from a cell instead of using the sheet name directly?

Tags: excel, indexing, formula

I need the following formula to be changed to take the name of the sheet from cell B29 instead of using `Sheet1`:

```
=IF(B29<>"",(IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!L:L,MATCH(C29,Sheet1!B:B,0)),"")),"")
```

[image: Screenshot of formula and cell B29]

How can exchange `Sheet1` by the content of a cell? Ex: INDEX(B29!L:L,Match(...))  (I think a solution could be INDIRECT but I don't know how to use it in this context)

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I managed to fix it:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&B$29&"'!L:L"),MATCH(C29,INDIRECT("'"&B$29&"'!B:B"),0)),"")
```